# I Can't Log In to my Account after Password reset

Tags: ubuntu, password, data-recovery, ecryptfs

I forgot the password to my admin account in ubuntu, I googled how to reset ubuntu admin password, then did the following steps from the tutorial that I found online

Enter Recovery

Drop to root shell

mount -o remount,rw /

passwd username

Enter new UNIX password

Retype new UNIX password

It said password updated successfully.

Now when I try to log in the password gets accepted but I get returned back to log in screen. But when I opened terminal from log in screen using CTRL + ALT + F1 I was able to log in to my account from terminal with the new password, I can see there are two files there named 'Access Your private Data.desktop' & 'Readme.txt' What does this mean?

Now, I had the old password written down, but it is was at my home, and I was in another city, thats why I decided to reset but now I am locked out after entering password it just bounces back to Log In Screen.

Now I am back home I have my old password in my hands, what do I do now? I really need access to my HOME directory so I can take a backup of some important files.

Would changing the password back to the original old password using RECOVERY PASSWD work? I don't have a back up of HOME, How do I take a backup of encrypted HOME before attempting to change the password back to the old one? I'm in a bit of a panic, and am worried I'm going to screw things up more.I am really new to ubuntu, only been using it for the past 7 months.

Comment: When you do the login via CLI - do you have access to your files, i.e. is home decrypted? It sounds more like you were stuck in a login-loop rather than the password change being a matter. How was home encrypted. Did your online guide take encrypted homes into account?

Answer (score 1):

I changed the password back to old one & it worked!!! The tutorial that I read did not account for the people who may have checked the option to encrypt HOME at the time of ubuntu install.